# Moodle api Webservice params

Tags: php, moodle

I need to create courses with dates where people can register.
I found all the calls at this link https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions

Unfortunately I did not find the parameters that are required for the creation.

The only project I found very well done is this https://github.com/guilhermebferreira/moodlerest

Thanks to the project on github I managed to create categories and courses but I do not understand how to create an event with dates where people can register.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any standard Moodle functionality that supports creating an 'event with dates where people can register'. The closest is a 3rd-party plugin called [Facetoface](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_facetoface). Last time I checked, the Facetoface plugin did not have any support for webservices, so that is something you'd need a developer to add, before you could use it that way.